# Amazon Aurora db with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius

I need some help, I was working with mysql and doctrine and all was perfect, but now I'm using Auroradb which uses two instances (reader and writer).
At first I tried to use two entity managers, one for writing and other for reading, but I got a problem with SyliusRbacBundle.

so, is there another way to use aurora and doctrine?????

**UPDATE 1**

this is the error that I get after using Daniel's config

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Litigon\UserBundle\Entity\User#authorizationRoles' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: SuperAdministrador. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

so, if I merge the default entity manager as a lot of people suggest, I get problems with aurora 'cause of the other manager is for the reader instance and then when flushing aurora says that isn't allowed to write.

Comment: please provide more information. What problem you got with SyliusRbacBundle. Is there some error message? Do you have any code you can copy here to make it more clearer.

Comment: Ok, I'll be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify where the models or entities actually live in doctrine config, also is important to notice that Sylius models are usually located on the component and not in the bundle. Finally, but not least important, can only have one connection with auto mapping:

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    loggable:
                        type: annotation
                        alias: Gedmo
                        prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                    FOSUserBundle:
                        type: xml
                        dir: Resources/config/doctrine-mapping
                        prefix: FOS\UserBundle\Model
                    SyliusRbacBundle:
                      type: xml
                      dir: Resources/config/doctrine/model
                      prefix: Sylius\Component\Rbac\Model
                    SyliusResourceBundle: ~
                    OtherBundle: ~
            writer:
                connection: writer
                mappings:
                    loggable:
                        type: annotation
                        alias: Gedmo
                        prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                    FOSUserBundle:
                      type: xml
                      dir: Resources/config/doctrine-mapping
                      prefix: FOS\UserBundle\Model
                    SyliusRbacBundle:
                        type: xml
                        dir: Resources/config/doctrine/model
                        prefix: Sylius\Component\Rbac\Model
                    SyliusResourceBundle: ~
```

Comment: This config helps me a lot but now I got another problem, I'll edit the question with both troubles.